# Azure Powershell commands for Azure AD management

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

**Context**

I am co-admin of an Azure subscription.

- I created Azure active directory in the same.
- I started the Azure Powershell.
- Azure account was added successfully.

**Problem**

But, when I fire the command `"Get-AzureADUser"`, it fails to provide the needed.

Also, when I tried with putting proper input like valid objectID, It did not return any value.

**Question**

To what Azure AD does the Azure Powershell command `"Get-AzureADUser"` establishes connection with?

Comment: I know that you were answering your own question, but an error detail message will help clarify what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

"Get-AzureADUser" command works with AzureResourceManager mode.
It calls the "Default directory" of the Azure subscription. 
It can only be authenticated with the credentials of Service Administrator of that 
subscription.
It works fine if the above mentioned are followed.